# Qt save location widget

Tags: qt, widget, savefiledialog

Do you know if there is such a widget in the Qt, that is at the same time a line edit and a open folder dialog button?

Please see example of what I am looking for.

EDIT: so, I am looking for something like editable ComboBox which opens a dialog when clicked on...

With kind regards,
Leta

[image: Save location example marked in red]

Comment: There's no such widget in Qt, but it's not hard to make one up :)